# JPA Criteria Build how to use Order By Clause with ASC NULLS FIRST

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, criteriaquery

How can I use the "order by" clause with "asc nulls first"?

This is my code:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<MyClassModel> query = builder.createQuery(MyClassModel.class);

//esprToOrder is a Expression<?> istance that containing the sort field...
query.orderBy(builder.asc(esprToOrder));

TypedQuery<MyClassModel> myQ = em.createQuery(query);

List<MyClassModel> myList = myQ.getResultList();
```

myList doesn't contain any records with null field sort...

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have formatted your code. [Check out](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24762045/edit) how I did - basically 4 spaces for code blocks. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for more help about how to ask. What do you mean with _myList doesn't contain any records with null field sort_?

Comment: Hi perissf, thanks. myList hasn't the records with sort field null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPA doesn't support specification of "NULLS FIRST|LAST". Some implementations may allow it (by casting to allow extra methods), but it's not part of the JPA spec.